# Считывание функции вида f(x) для дальнейшей работы с ней

Tags: java, android, калькулятор, интегральное-исчисление

помогите пожалуйста.
Задача состоит в том, что бы программа на java считывала функцию введеную в консоль (ну или в будущем в EditText в AndroidStudio). Я пишу калькулятор интегралов, и столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу придумать способ считывания функции.
Ниже представлен код, который считает примерное значение интеграла для y=x^2. Надо что бы программа принимала String например:(x^2-2+x)/20 и выполняла все что указано в коде, только для введеной функции.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
            /*входные данные, вместо первого значения должна вводиться функция. 
              Второе и третье значение - это пределы интеграла, а четвертое - dx.*/
            func(0,-1,1,0.001);
    }
    public static int func(int func, int f, int s, double dx){
//объявляется массив под площади под графиком
        double[] members;
//Считается количество малых площадей, а затем округляется до большего целого числа
        double g = (s-f)/dx;
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###");
        int result  = Integer.parseInt(decimalFormat.format(g));
        int i = 0;
        double a = f; 
//Запускается цикл который находит значение функциии и умножает его на dx, добавляя в ячейку массива
        members = new double[result];
        while(i < result){
            double sqa = a * a * dx;
            a = a + dx;
            members[i] = sqa;
            //System.out.println(members[i]);
            i++;
        }
//находит сумму малых площадей
        double sum = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < result; x++) {
            sum = sum + members[x];
            System.out.println(sum);

        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: разбор подобных выражений - это рекурсия с разбивкой по скобкам и приоритетов операций -вычисление по ветвям деревьев в конечный результат, вы уверены что с этим справитесь?

Comment: @Style-7, я только учусь, не имею до конца представления на сколько это сложно. Если нет возможности за раз расписать эту идею, то если вам не сложно, посоветуйте где можно узнать об этом по подробнее. Может есть какие-то статьи?

Comment: ну я уже дал вам направление, можно прочитать про простейший интерпретатор языка программирования, в вашем случае будет проще без переменных

Comment: @Style-7, благодарю, кажется понимаю о чем вы говорите. Изучу информацию!)